# How to divide a data set into three different vectors based on peaks

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a large data set that, when graphed, resembles the graph of sin(x)+1 with three peaks. I want to integrate under each peak and get three different areas. I do not know the coordinate location of the peak, and I cannot assume that I know the wavelength. So I need to find the three peaks and separate the data into three corresponding vectors. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what is your ultimate goal? *"to integrate under each peak and get three different areas"* or *"separate the data into three corresponding vectors"*?

Comment: My goal is to get three different areas. The dataset is initially in one huge vector, and I wanted to separate it into three different vectors and use trapz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want using the [`findpeaks`](https://mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) function. Take the following example:

We generate two vectors `x` and `y` of data:

```
x = linspace(0, 5*pi);  % x data.
y = sin(x) + 1;         % y data.
```

Then we use `findpeaks` to find the peaks of our dataset and retrieve their indexes (`locs`):

```
>> [~, locs] = findpeaks(y)

locs =

    11    51    90
```

We can see that the function has found 3 peaks with coordinates: `[x(11), y(11)]`, `[x(51), y(51)]` and `[x(90), y(90)]`.

By calling `findpeaks` without output arguments we can get a plot of the data with the peak values overlaid which is often useful for a visual verification:

```
>> findpeaks(y)
```

[image: signal with peaks overlaid]

We can divide our dataset very easily with the following [`for`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html) loop, and store the different subsets in a [cell array](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html):

```
n = numel(locs);
for i = 1:n + 1
    if i == 1
        x_cell{i} = x(1:locs(i));
        y_cell{i} = y(1:locs(i));
    elseif i <= n
        x_cell{i} = x(locs(i-1):locs(i));
        y_cell{i} = y(locs(i-1):locs(i));
    else
        x_cell{i} = x(locs(i-1):end);
        y_cell{i} = y(locs(i-1):end);
    end
end
```

This will give us:

```
K>> x_cell

x_cell =

  1×4 cell array

    [1×11 double]    [1×41 double]    [1×40 double]    [1×11 double]
```

and

```
K>> y_cell

y_cell =

  1×4 cell array

    [1×11 double]    [1×41 double]    [1×40 double]    [1×11 double]
```

So we have divided our dataset successfully. Each cell contains a subset of the original dataset.

Now we can use [`trapz`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html) inside a `for` loop to find the numerical integration of each subset:

```
k = numel(y_cell);
for i = 1:k
    A(i) = trapz(x_cell{i}, y_cell{i});
end
```

These are the results:

```
>> A

A =

    2.6004    6.4099    6.0931    2.6004
```

Finally I thought it would be nice to plot the different regions together using the [`area`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/area.html) function and a `for` loop:

```
hold on;
for i = 1:k
    area(x_cell{i}, y_cell{i}, 'FaceColor', i/k*[1, 1, 1]);
end
hold off; axis tight;
grid on; box on;
```

The different regions are clearly visible here:

[image: area plot of different regions]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used a very similar solution to the one you used. My data had many "peaks", so I ended up using the findpeaks function, ordering the peaks from highest y-value to lowest, and then throwing out values until my top 3 elements were a certain distance apart on the x axis. Then I individually calibrated and integrated under each curve. It ended up working pretty well for as many peaks as I needed to look for